# Use shell script function directly on bash

Tags: bash, source

I have a utilitarian shell script full of goodies and wish to bring them to the bash environment. I used the command `source` before as analogous to `import` or `include` in other languages.

`printer.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

printAwesome () {
    echo "Awesome!"
}

printMoo () {
    echo "Moo!"
}
```

I think it is only running the command `source printer.sh` on terminal. Is it really? Do we have any other procedure to follow?

In python, we have environments which we `activate` and `deactivate`.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to have `printMoo` available as if you were using `from printer import printMoo` in Python?

Comment: "I used the command `source` before..." vs. "I think _it_ is only running the command `source printer.sh` on terminal." -- what or who is the "it" that is running something there in the second sentence? What do you mean with only running the command "on terminal"?

Comment: Can you [edit] to add an example of how you're trying to use those functions? Better yet, add a full printout of what you're doing, including the files involved _and_ the error messages you get (along with what you expected to happen)

Comment: The answer marked as the answer satisfies me very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what it is you are trying to achieve, then loading your file with `source` is not enough. If you wish to use `printer.sh` as a module, you need to `export` each function's name that should be available outside your script. So `printer.sh` should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printAwesome () {
    echo "Awesome!"
}

printMoo () {
    echo "Moo!"
}

export -f printAwesome
export -f printMoo
```

And then you can write something like this in `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source printer.sh
echo "Let's run these functions ..."
printAwesome
printMoo
echo "Hey, that works now!"
```

Comment: There is no need to `export` the functions if you are just using them in the same shell that does the sourcing.  There is also no need to keep the `#!`-line on the script that you source as this will just be treated as a comment.

Comment: I already created an alias on dotfile `.bashrc`, which may work for some punctual cases. In this case now, I wish to import in another context, like a bash session.

Comment: When I try without the export stuff, my bash crashes. I will try with `export -f`

Comment: @Kusalananda: I remember finding out about this trick exactly because omitting `export` didn't work. Can you explain which case would **require** it?

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre if you define some function in script A and execute (not source) another script B from *within* A, then B can use functions that are exported by A. Exporting is not needed when B is sourcing A (like in the answer).

Comment: @muru: Thanks for the clarification.